# I want to hook up a couple active speakers to my icom 9100 so I have a good range and good volume . the output on the receiver is 8ohms

Tags: equipment-troubleshooting, audio

Can I just plug a 4 ohm powered speaker set into the output of the 9100's speaker output, or will that damage the Icom's amp?

Comment: The 9100 has two speaker outputs and a phones output. You'll probably want to specify which you mean. The speaker outputs support 4-8ohm impedance. All of this is in the owner's manual.